# How to run GitHub Actions workflow only if a new file is pushed

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Let's say that I have an **`action`** like such:

```yaml
    name: Another_Action
    on:
      push:
        - ...
      pull_request:
        - ...
```

And I want it so that it **only** runs **when a new file is committed**.

I've got some options from the autocomplete:

| Option | Would help? |
| --- | --- |
| branches | Nope |
| branches-ignore | Nope |
| tags | ??? |
| tags-ignore | ??? |
| **paths** | **Maybe** |
| **paths-ignore** | **Maybe** |
| types | ??? |

Using `paths-ignore` and listing all files and directories we already know of won't work since I want it automated and the directories won't stay the same forever.

I'm thinking of using `paths` for this since I already have used it in the past...

But I don't know how to use it **in this context**.

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: @rethab I have tried listing all the files first and adding them to paths-ignore, but it won't work on this context since the directory won't stay the same forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option. You can only abort the pipeline early by checking for new files after the checkout step has run

Comment: how can new file be identified after checkout? could you please elaborate?

Comment: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/changed-files